# Spring Boot 1.4 issue with Cucumber-JVM

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

When using Spring boot 1.4 with cucumber, @Autowired beans are not injected.

But when I use plain Junit tests, they are injected correctly!
I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836337/cucumber-with-spring-boot-1-4-dependencies-not-injected-when-using-springboott) but it doesn't solve my problem.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@ComponentScan("org.services")
public class ServicesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServicesApplication.class, args);
    }
}


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class UsersTest {

}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UsersSteps {

    @Autowired
    private UsersService _target;//null
}
```

Edit:
Just to clarify, I did view [Cucumber with Spring Boot 1.4: Dependencies not injected when using @SpringBootTest and @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836337/cucumber-with-spring-boot-1-4-dependencies-not-injected-when-using-springboott)
and put this annotations

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
```

didnt work

then I put these annotations (as in the answer)

```
@ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
```

didnt work either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cucumber with Spring Boot 1.4: Dependencies not injected when using @SpringBootTest and @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836337/cucumber-with-spring-boot-1-4-dependencies-not-injected-when-using-springboott)

Comment: @Jörn Horstmann i clearly reference the said question, saying that the answer didnt work for me.

Answer (score 1):

fixed

in pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber-junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In UsersSteps class

```
    @SpringBootTest
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = {ServicesApplication.class})
    @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
    public class UsersSteps
```

Comment: This works to me. My scene is that cucumber 1.2.5, spring boot 1.4.4 , and run the example from the book "spring boot cookbook', change the origin annotation to  @SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {BookPubApplication.class, TestMockBeansConfig.class})